# CherryPy with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I need a cherrypy RPC hierarchy like:

```
/a/foo/bar
/a/wilma/betty
/b/blee/blah
/b/mip/smip
/c/mumble/stumble
/c/fred/barney
```

...where /a, /b and /c are handled by a master process, dispatching based on these three prefixes to three different subprocesses.  I'm not sure yet if os.fork() or multiprocessing would be better for this.  I'm also not sure if it'd be better to use multiprocessing.Queue or wspbus.Bus for interprocess communication.

And despite being a pretty accomplished Python developer, I really don't know where to start.  I've googled quite a bit over the last 18 hours, and found pretty much nothing that looks  similar.

The goal is to have a REST-like RPC hierarchy in which (EG) all of /b can be restarted without impacting service of /a or /c by restarting the subprocess that serves /b.

BTW, we're planning to use RoutesDispatcher, but requesting info about that here is just too much; I'm afraid this question is already too specific to get answers. So, if someone has done this (or has thoughts on how to do it) with one of the Dispatchers that come with CherryPy, or indeed any CherryPy dispatcher, please let me know how you did (or could do) it!

Anyone?

Comment: Do you really need to dispatch the three process from a master process? or is just the convenience to have just one trigger, have you consider something like  https://www.varnish-cache.org/ and use routes from varnish to the specific port of each application?

Comment: I'd personally be happy with NGINX or similar doing the multiplexing onto a single RPC-REST URL space, but the requirement appears to be that a single piece of software serve up all 3.